# VS Code change theme color only for CSS

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, themes

I'm using [Atom One Dark Theme](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=akamud.vscode-theme-onedark) as a main theme in Visual Studio Code. For some reason CSS highlighting has 
been lost:

[image]

I discoverd that you can change coloring of basic tokens such as `comments` by editing `"editor.tokenColorCustomizations"`. But how do you change the CSS pair semantics from above?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out how you can achieve it. I used TextMate syntax format added to [`tokenColorCustomizations`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes#_semantic-highlighting) configuration within VS Code's `settings.json`. So this setting:

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "textMateRules": [
      {
        "name": "CSS Class and Support - Property Name",
        "scope": [
          "source.css support.type.property-name",
          "source.sass support.type.property-name",
          "source.scss support.type.property-name",
          "source.less support.type.property-name",
          "source.stylus support.type.property-name",
          "source.postcss support.type.property-name"
        ],
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#9CDCFE"
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "CSS Class and Support - Property Value",
        "scope": [
          "source.css support.type.property-value",
          "source.sass support.type.property-value",
          "source.scss support.type.property-value",
          "source.less support.type.property-value",
          "source.stylus support.type.property-value",
          "source.postcss support.type.property-value"
        ],
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#CE9178"
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "CSS Class and Support - Class",
        "scope": [
          "source.css entity.other.attribute-name.class.css",
          "source.sass entity.other.attribute-name.class.css",
          "source.scss entity.other.attribute-name.class.css",
          "source.less entity.other.attribute-name.class.css",
          "source.stylus entity.other.attribute-name.class.css",
          "source.postcss entity.other.attribute-name.class.css"
        ],
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#D7BA7D"
        }
      }
    }
```

would end up with that appearance inside css alike files:

[image]

For more information refer to [Syntax Highlight Guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide).

Answer (score 2):

```
  "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "textMateRules": [
      {
        "name": "CSS Attribute",
        "scope": "support.type.property-name.css",
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#91bfe3"
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "Shorthand property combines",
        "scope": "invalid.deprecated.color.system.css",
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#6fcba5"
        }
      },
    ],
  }
```

The value corresponding to `scope` can be obtained with the [scope inspector tool](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide#scope-inspector).

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> to open the Command Palette and then open up the `Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes` to look at the TextMate scope of the element you're interested in modifying.

Comment: Thank you for adding the `Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes` portion of your answer. That helped out a lot! Thank you!