# VSCode doesn't highlight nested classes properly when using parent selector in SCSS files

Tags: visual-studio-code, sass, syntax-highlighting

VSCode highlights nested classes with parent selector as properties in SCSS as seen here:

[image]

&__recommendation is highlighted in blue which is a bit confusing. Can i make it so vscode highlights it in yellow like a class selector? I'd like it to be like this(it's a .less file):

[image]

The code if someone needs to copypaste it:

```
.product-card {
    padding: 15px 27px;
    color: red;
    font-family: "DM Sans";
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 700;

    &__recommendation {
        display: flex;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to add in settings.json:

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "textMateRules": [
        {
            "scope": [
                "entity.name.tag.reference.scss",
                "entity.other.attribute-name.parent-selector-suffix.css"
            
            ],
            "settings": {
                "foreground": "#D7BA7D"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I've used Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes command to find which scopes i need

More information here: 
[VS Code change theme color only for CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61863436/vs-code-change-theme-color-only-for-css) 
https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide

https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/color-theme#syntax-colors

https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/semantic-highlight-guide#theming

Comment: Thanks, this worked here too. I removed `"entity.name.tag.reference.scss"` to keep the coloured `&`, but the class name is now coloured as you'd expect 